# textarea additional whitespace at beginning

Tags: php, html, textarea, whitespace

I have some data in database and want allow user to edit a field like description of product and sometimes it might be long to I wanna put already existing value into textarea so the user will already have old description in textarea and just add or delete some text. The problem is that I have some additional whitespaces at beginning and end of textarea even though there is no whitespace in this text I even echo that variable to make sure there is no space. I even trim my variable to remove it but it doesn't change anything.

It looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TVXR.png

I want to get rid of these whitespaces

Html code:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="text">
                            <?php 
                            $info = trim($row['description']);
                            echo $info;?>
                            </textarea>
```

Php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE id_shop = '$id_shop'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: What about the whitespace between `<textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="text">` and `<?php`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove all extra whitespace before during and after the php.

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="text"><?php $info = trim($row['description']);echo $info;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is lots of spaces before

```
                        <?php
```

e.q. 
many spaces then  < ? php ...